# Command console to generate a twig template in symfony 4

Tags: templates, command, twig, symfony4

I keep rereading the symfony 4 documentation to try to generate twig template  with the console  commands but I did not  find  a  command . Is there any one  know a bundle to  generate twig template with console commands ?

Comment: I'm not at home now so I cannot check, but first install maker (composer require maker --dev) then check if there is a command for view (bin/console list make). If there is, it is there :)

Comment: Why the console would be usefull to generate a blank file `template.html.twig` ? (it's not a troll, i'm really curious)

Comment: @goto not blank, with some code already in it. CakePHP for example can generate a full CRUD with one console command based on a database table. So I'm guessing something like that was what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm solved

```
 class SendEmailNotify extends Command
{
    private $container;
    private $twig;
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct($name = null, \Psr\Container\ContainerInterface $container, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->twig = $this->container->get('twig');
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked it and the sad answer is no. The list of maker commands is available [here](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/tree/master/src/Maker). You can even make a twig extension, but not a view. It is worth submitting to them I think.

Comment: can you explain me what is  the  twig extension exactly ?

Comment: Sure, it is an additional filter or function for twig, like for instance {{ variable | length }} (the lenght part). So sadly nothing that would help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I needed Twig functionality to send emails from my custom console command.

This is the solution I came up with.

First I installed Twig.

```
composer require "twig/twig:^2.0"
```

Then created my own twig service.

```
<?php

# src/Service/Twig.php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class Twig extends \Twig_Environment {

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel) {
        $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($kernel->getProjectDir());

        parent::__construct($loader);
    }
}
```

Now my email command looks like this.

```
<?php

# src/Command/EmailCommand.php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command,
    Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface,
    Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface,
    App\Service\Twig;

class EmailCommand extends Command {

    protected static $defaultName = 'mybot:email';

    private $mailer,
            $twig;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, Twig $twig) {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->twig = $twig;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure() {
        $this->setDescription('Email bot.');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {

        $template = $this->twig->load('templates/email.html.twig');

        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
            ->setFrom('emailbot@domain.com')
            ->setTo('someone@somewhere.com')
            ->setBody(
                $template->render(['name' => 'Fabien']),
                'text/html'
            );

        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This instruction will make a Controller without a twig template

```
php bin/console make:controller --no-template
```

Surprisingly this instruction will make a Controller and a template file and subdirectory

```
php bin/console make:controller
```